# Search from ArrayList and output objects to be a new menu

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

My code to search from ArrayList:

```
public void searchFromList() {
        String color;
        System.out.print("Input the color: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        color = scan.nextLine();
        boolean test = false;
        for (Fruit fruit: fruits) {
            if (fruit.getcolor().equals(color)) {
                System.out.println(fruit);
                test = true;
            }
        }
        if (!test){
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Sorry there is no " + color + " fruit in list");
        }
    }
```

If input is "green", output will be:

```
01 Pear
03 Watermelon
```

How do I make the output be a menu like:

```
[1] 01 Pear
[2] 03 Watermelon
[3] Back to Menu
```

Thank you! This is not an assignment, please feel free to give advice!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than a for-each loop, use an iterated loop and the use iterator as part of the output.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= fruits.length; i++) {
    Fruit fruit = fruits[i - 1];
    // including your stuff
    System.out.printf ("[%d] %s%n", i, fruit);
    
}
```

**not tested or even compiled**

Comment: As `i` is used for printing with `1` being added to it, I decided to do it this way for the OP to understand.  Probably for myself, I would index from `0` though.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a counter to check the number of fruits found, and then use this counter to construct the menu form.

Your code would be like this:

```
public void searchFromList() {
        String color;
        System.out.print("Input the color: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        color = scan.nextLine();
        boolean test = false;
        // Add Menu Item Counter Here
        int itemCount = 0;
        for (Fruit fruit: fruits) {
            if (fruit.getcolor().equals(color)) {
                System.out.println("[" + ++itemCount + "]" + fruit);
                test = true;
            }
        }
        if (!test){
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Sorry there is no " + color + " fruit in list");
        }
        // Print Menu Item Here
        System.out.println("[" + ++itemCount + "] Back To Menu");
    }
```